# Python Fuzzy LookUp (Fuzzy Match) from two different csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lookup, fuzzywuzzy

Help with a FuzzyLookup in between two different CSV files (which contain company info).

CSV #1 data1.csv has two columns as well (5 thousand rows)
Name, ID
CSV #2 data2.csv has two columns (1.05 million rows)
LegalName, AcctNumber

The target would be to do a FuzzyLookup of Name to LegalNames
(show two matching LegalNames based on a percentage of accuracy would be ideal)

I saw that there is the following library:
https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy

Plus, the following GitHub shows a similar idea of what I want to do
https://github.com/Cheukting/fuzzy-match-company-name

Which uses Pandas and FuzzyWuzzy

Hers was helpful since she also tries to filter the most common names in a company name (such as "a," "the," 'LLC," "Ltd," "and," etc.)

The only thing is that from my understanding, hers compares if there are duplicates within the same list, not within two different ones. So, it would be ideal to have the same concept across data1.csv and data2.csv

Also, feel free to contribute with a method that uses a different library as well! Any help is welcomed :)

Below is her code:

---

The data we used is found on http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/en_output.html it is an openly licensed publicly avalible dataset that contains a list of registered (limited liability) companies in Great Britain. (the version shown here is snapshot of May 2018)

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 1000)
df = pd.read_csv("BasicCompanyDataAsOneFile-2020-10-01.csv")
df.head()
```

This is a huge table with lots of rows, it may take a while to load

```
df.columns
df['RegAddress.PostTown'].value_counts().head(30)
```

Frequency of words
Since we have lots of companies, we will only use companies in Cambridge as an example.

First we find the 30 most common words in all company names. As we will be expecting them to be repeating a lot even in companies that is not the same, we cannot match company names using them. The way we do it is we will deduct the matching score of a pair if any keywords is present in the names.

```
from collections import Counter
all_names = df['CompanyName'][df['RegAddress.PostTown']=='CAMBRIDGE'].unique()
names_freq = Counter()
for name in all_names:
    names_freq.update(str(name).split(" "))
key_words = [word for (word,_) in names_freq.most_common(30)]
print(key_words)
```

Show length

```
len(all_names)
```

Matching by Grouping
Then we group the names by their 1st character. As the list is too long, it will take forever to match them all at once (15889 x 15889 pairs to consider). The work around is to match them by groups, assuming if the names are not matched at the 1st character, it is unlikely that they are the same name.

```
all_main_name = pd.DataFrame(columns=['sort_gp','names','alias','score'])
all_names.sort()
all_main_name['names'] = all_names
all_main_name['sort_gp'] = all_main_name['names'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

Fuzzy Matching
Here for each group, we use fuzzywuzzy.token_sort_ratio to matching the names. Different form the basic fuzzywuzzy.ratio which use Levenshtein Distance to calculate the differences, it allow the token (words) in a name to swap order and still give a 'perfect' match. (ref: https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy)

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

all_sort_gp = all_main_name['sort_gp'].unique()

def no_key_word(name):
    """check if the name contain the keywords in travel company"""
    output = True
    for key in key_words:
        if key in name:
            output = False
    return output

for sortgp in all_sort_gp:
    this_gp = all_main_name.groupby(['sort_gp']).get_group(sortgp)
    gp_start = this_gp.index.min()
    gp_end = this_gp.index.max()
    for i in range(gp_start,gp_end+1):
    
        # if self has not got alias, asign to be alias of itself
        if pd.isna(all_main_name['alias'].iloc[i]):
            all_main_name['alias'].iloc[i] = all_main_name['names'].iloc[i]
            all_main_name['score'].iloc[i] = 100
        
        # if the following has not got alias and fuzzy match, asign to be alias of this one
        for j in range(i+1,gp_end+1):
            if pd.isna(all_main_name['alias'].iloc[j]):
                fuzz_socre = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(all_main_name['names'].iloc[i],all_main_name['names'].iloc[j])
                if not no_key_word(all_main_name['names'].iloc[j]):
                    fuzz_socre -= 10
                if (fuzz_socre > 85):
                    all_main_name['alias'].iloc[j] = all_main_name['alias'].iloc[i]
                    all_main_name['score'].iloc[j] = fuzz_socre
                    
        if i % (len(all_names)//10) == 0:
            print("progress: %.2f" % (100*i/len(all_names)) + "%")
                
all_main_name.to_csv('company_in_cambridge.csv')
```

Preview

```
all_main_name[(all_main_name['names']!=all_main_name['alias']) & (all_main_name['alias'].notna())]
```

Thanks!

Expected answer:

```
all_main_name[(all_main_name['names']!=all_main_name['alias']) & (all_main_name['alias'].notna())]
```

sort_gp,    names,          alias,          score
955,    A,  AMADEUS EII LP, AMADEUS EI LP,  96
956,    A,  AMADEUS EIII LP,    AMADEUS EI LP,  93
957,    A,  AMADEUS GI LP,  AMADEUS EI LP,  92
958,    A,  AMADEUS HI LP,  AMADEUS EI LP,  92
960,    A,  AMADEUS II 'A', AMADEUS I,      86

Comment: What is your _specific question_?

Comment: @DYZ The code above compares within the same list/csv. I am trying to compare two differnent lists "Name" under data1.csv to "LegalName" under data2.csv

Comment: But what is your _question_? What are you asking, and what kind of answer you expect to get?

Comment: @DYZ I have attached the expected output layout. The code above gives such a result of the similarity between Name and Alias from the same CSV. I would like to change so that the Name now comes from  "Name" data1.csv and "Alias" "LegalName" data2.csv. So, I hope to set up the variables right and use the code above. I am not sure how to since I tried different ways already. Also, it doesn't have to be limited to her way. Open to suggestions. I have never used fuzzywuzzy before.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that you get an answer to your question: it is very unfocused. I suggest that you rewrite it [according to the best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DYZ Thanks for the feedback. I think I understand it because I have the idea but I can sew why it is not easy to see as a third party. I just wasn't sure if it was an easy swap of variables or more complicated. So, that is why I gave it a shot. After the explanation do you have a better understanding?